# LZMA compression algorithm - when it's worth it

Tags: compression, lzma

We use LZMA compression algorithm in our code base. Now I heard a theory that whenever the size of my byte buffer is below value X (let's say 4K) it's not worth to compress since not a lot of space will be saved (if any). Before I start benchmarking the system with&without this check, can anybody point me toward the answer (didn't find it with google)..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your data. This is an easy experiment to do. Simply compress a large number of different sized chunks extracted from examples of your data. See how LZMA performs. Pick a threshold. Done.